# CustomValidator OnServerValidate Method Determine Validator ID Received

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, customvalidator

I am thinking my answer may be no, but wanted to verify if I am able to grab the ID from the `CustomValidator` in the method that the `CustomValidator` calls. I say this because I have created a `CustomValidator` method that does the same thing for multiple date fields. However, I would like to make the `RequiredValidator` `Visible=False` for each of the controls, on a case by case basis, so that they don't take up space like they do when they are set to `visibility:hidden` in the `span`.

Can I do this? I haven't been able to find anything that even addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this as a solution.

```
        CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)sender;
        if (cv != null && cv.ID != null)
        {
            string cvID = cv.ID.ToString();

            switch (cvID)
            {
                case "CustValidEMIActionOffDate":
                    reqEMIActionOffDate.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case "CustValidSignatureDateTextBox":
                    reqSigDate.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case "CustValidPrimaryDateTextBox":
                    reqPrimaryDate.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case "CustValidAltDateTextBox":
                    reqAltDate.Visible = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In the page load I added this to offset the hidden elements. Probably should test to see if they are `Visible=false` first, but that can be added later.

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        reqEMIActionOffDate.Visible = true;
        reqSigDate.Visible = true;
        reqPrimaryDate.Visible = true;
        reqAltDate.Visible = true;
    }
```